# React - State not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

When the user clicks the Upvote button, the render increments the value however it does not update the data state.

Although, if the user clicks upvote twice (eg: 50, 51, 52), it then saves the value as 51.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(props);
const [update] = useUpdateSnippet();

// TODO: Implement upvote functionality
const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    setData(previousData => {
      return { 
        ...previousData, 
        votes: data.votes+1
      }
    });
    console.log(data);
    update({
      snippetId: data.id,
      body: data,
      onUpdated: () => {}
    });
  }, 
  [update, data]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) has an additional argument where you can pass a callback function, which is guaranteed to run right after state has been updated. Something like this - `setState(updater, callback)`.

From the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), ... which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

Here is my snippet which you might apply:

```js
setData({ 
    ...previousData, 
    votes: data.votes+1
  },
  () => {
    console.log(data);
    // your update function call
    update();
  });
```

Comment: This is not available with hooks and the snippet in OP is in hooks.

Answer (score 0):

State update doesn't happen synchronously so `update` would not get the updated `data` state.

Store the updated data in a variable and pass that to `setData` as well as `update`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(props);
const [update] = useUpdateSnippet();

// TODO: Implement upvote functionality
const onClick = useCallback(() => {
  const newData = { ...data, votes: data.votes + 1 };
  setData(newData);
  console.log(data);
  update({ snippetId: newData.id, body: newData, onUpdated: () => {} });
}, [update, data]);
```

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem consider upvoting & accepting it as an answer. @ChrisPantelli